# How to Combine 3d Plots

Tags: plotting, overlay

I am trying to analyze data from a high-altitude balloon (HAB) launched in Ohio, and I would like to use Mathematica to do this. Currently, I have used Mathematica to generate a plot of the topography of Ohio. I plan to use Mathematica to plot data regarding the coordinates and altitude of the HAB throughout its flight. Is there a way to either combine the separate plots of the topography of Ohio and the (x,y,z) coordinates of the HAB or to plot the coordinates and altitude of the HAB on the topography of Ohio?

Comment: Please show the code you have so far, and the data you are trying to plot.

Comment: You might be looking for the "Show" function which will allow you to combine several plots.

Comment: So let's say the balloon is at (x1,y1) at a height of 100m from sea level. The point on the terrain right beneath it is a hill at 50m. Thus the balloon has a clearance of 50m. Are you trying to plot clearance (or some other metric) given the balloon path as a series of (x,y) points?